# Joining two tables with Composite Primary Keys that do not match

Tags: sql, tableau-api, composite-primary-key

I have two tables one `Position Allocation`, the other `Ownership`.

`Ownership` has a composite key made up of these columns:

```
AS_OF_DATE, OWNED_PORT_CD, DEAL_OR_SCHEDULE, DEAL_SCHED_NO, OWNER_PORT_CD
```

The `Position Allocation` table has a composite key made up of

```
AS_OF_DATE, PORT_CD, POSITN_NUM, BOOK_CD_NME, DEAL_OR_SCHEDULE, DEAL_SCHED_NO
```

These are the join conditions that exist

```
Ownership  OWNED_PORT_CD     Position_Allocation PORT_CD
Ownership  AS_OF_DATE        Position_Allocation AS_OF_DATE
Ownership  DEAL_OR_SCHEDULE  Position_Allocation DEAL_OR_SCHEDULE
Ownership  DEAL_SCHED_NO     Position_Allocation DEAL_SCHED_NO
```

Which leaves `Ownership.OWNER_PORT_CD` which is a foreign key to another table
and `Position_Allocation.PORT_CD`, and `POSITN_NUM`

Long story short is there a way to join these? I attached all the columns.

`Ownership` table

[image: Ownership Table]

`Position Allocation` table:

[image: Position Allocation]

All columns:

[image: All columns]

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results as tabular text. Also, what have you tried so far? If you know the join conditions, it shouldn't be to hard to write the query.

Comment: I have tried to join everything in Tableau and the problem I have is I am not able to combine the ownership table in without getting incorrect results. I guess what I really am wondering is How do I join the Ownership table to the position allocation table. Neither tables have the required columns.

Comment: Long story short I guess I just need to know how to join Position Allocation to Ownership and I have been able to do the rest.

Comment: A join between 2 tables represents a *relationship* between the entities stored in the tables. So first ask yourself, what exactly does a row in each of your tables represent- what does a relationship between them mean? What is the cardinality of that relationship? One to one? One to many? Many to many? With that info about your data model, you can think about what kind of join would reflect the relationship you have in mind

Comment: The sad news is that just because two physical tables have some columns in common, that does not always mean that the data model makes logical sense or that there are clear unambiguous relationships between them. That’s why it is sometimes necessary to do some data reshaping transformations or data wrangling to prepare the data into a form that supports the analysis you want to perform.

Comment: Tables with long composite keys that almost match are a symptom that you may need to do some data wrangling first. Tableau Prep Builder can be useful in this step. It may help to think about how you would ideally like the data to organized to simplify your analysis

Comment: Thank you Alex I will check that out. I know some wrangling is needed. This one is driving me crazy.